# JavaScript inheritance rules

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Learning JS in codecademy, confused about some technicalities regarding inheritance on lesson 18/30.

Penguin is a subclass of Animal.

I set Penguin's prototype to Animal, and in the Penguin constructor I specified its numLegs. However, I did not specify its name and food, which are properties of the Animal class.

The Penguin constructor only takes 1 parameter, name, whereas the Animal constructor takes 3: name, food, and numLegs.

If I create a new Penguin object named "Bob", for instance, what will its numLegs and food be?

```
// the original Animal class and sayName method

function Animal(name, numLegs, food) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
    this.food = food;

}
Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};

// define a Penguin class
function Penguin(name)
{
    this.numLegs=2;
    this.name=name;
}

// set its prototype to be a new instance of Animal
Penguin.prototype=new Animal();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`food` is a property that is initialized in the `Animal()` constructor when it is called with three parameters passed to it.  Since you are never calling the constructor that way with those arguments and you are never setting the `food` property in your `Penguin` constructor, that property will be `undefined` (never set).

The `numLegs` property will have a value of `2` because your `Penguin` constructor always sets it to `2`.

The `name` property will be set because you are setting it in your `Penguin` constructor.  There is only one object here.  It's not like there's a `Penguin` part of the object and an `Animal` part of the object.  There's just one object and one set of properties.  No matter where the property is set (which constructor or which method), once it is set, it's set on the object.

The usual method of inheritance is to create a constructor for `Penguin` that includes ALL the properties needed to initialize the object (or the subclass manually sets some of the arguments itself) and then in the `Penguin` constructor, you call the constructor of the base object and pass it the arguments that it expects.

Here would be one way to do that where the `Penguin` constructor calls the `Animal` constructor and passes the arguments for `numLegs` and `food` since they are already known for a `Penguin` and thus don't need to be passed in with the `Penguin` constructor.

```
function Animal(name, numLegs, food) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
    this.food = food;
}

Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};

// define a Penguin class
function Penguin(name) {
    // call parent constructor with this object and all three args it wants
    // so all the object properties get initialized appropriately
    Animal.call(this, name, 2, "fish");
}

// set its prototype to be a new instance of Animal
Penguin.prototype = new Animal();
```

---

FYI, the more modern way to set the prototype is:

```
Penguin.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

This avoids any side effects of the constructor and just copies the desired prototype.  `Object.create()` requires IE9 or a simple polyfill.