# JavaScript private variables, functions

Tags: javascript, variables, private

Learning JavaScript on codecademy, have several questions about lesson 24/30

In the code below:

1. why does `john.getBalance()` (last line) not result in an error when the getBalance function was not declared as `this.prototype.getBalance` but as `this.getBalance`? I thought subclasses could only use the functions of superclasses if they were declared with "prototype".
2. What is the difference between declaring the function `this.getBalance` vs `Person.getBalance`?
3. Is declaring the function inside vs outside the constructor just a convention or does it make a functional difference?
4. If `bankBalance` is private, how do I know what functions are allowed to access it? Why is `getBalance` in the code allowed to access `bankBalance`?

#### My code :

```
function Person(first,last,age) {
    this.firstname = first;
    this.lastname = last;
    this.age = age;
    var bankBalance = 7500;
  
    this.getBalance = function() {
        // your code should return the bankBalance
        return bankBalance;
    };
}

var john = new Person('John','Smith',30);
console.log(john.bankBalance); //undefined

// create a new variable myBalance that calls getBalance()
console.log(myBalance=john.getBalance());
```

Comment: prototype gives you performance benefits. it enables sharing a method across numerous instances.without prototype each object would have its own method which in turn results in more memory.having a method shared through protoype is not a mandatory requirement.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) why does `john.getBalance()` (last line) not result in an error when the `getBalance` function was not declared as `this.prototype.getBalance` but as `this.getBalance`? I thought subclasses could only use the functions of superclasses if they were declared with "prototype".

As I said in [my answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277838/javascript-inheritance-rules), there is only one set of properties.  Javascript will look first on the object itself and if no property match is found there, it will look on the prototype.  There is no separate set of properties that belong to subclass and separate set for superclass.  There is one set of properties directly on the object and there is a defined lookup order (for how to search the prototypes) if no matching property is found directly the object itself, but it is logically one overall set of properties on the object (and a method is just a property with a function for its value).  There is not one set of properties that belong to the superclass and one set to the subclass.  In Javascript you should not think of it that way (I know it feels like that in some other languages, but it isn't that way in javascript).

> 2) What is the difference between declaring the function `this.getBalance` vs Person.getBalance?

`this.getBalance` refers to a method on a specific object.

`Person.getBalance` refers to a property on the `Person` constructor which is not something you've declared.

If you mean the difference between declaring `this.getBalance` and `Person.prototype.getBalance`, then the main difference is where the function is found in the lookup order.  Both will be found on any `Person` object or any object derived from a `Person` object.  Technically it is more efficient for the runtime if you declare it on the prototype because there is only one shared instance of the function object rather than creating a new instance of the function object for each instance of `Person`, but operationally they are the same.  Using the prototype is preferred unless there is a specific reason not to.

> 3)  Is declaring the function inside vs outside the constructor just a convention or does it make a functional difference?

It is more efficient to declare methods on the prototype, but they can also be declared in the constructor and there is little operational difference except that methods declared in the constructor have access to local variables declared in the constructor which can be used as private instance variables.  Using the prototype is preferred unless there is a specific reason not to.

> 4)  If bankBalance is private, how do I know what functions are allowed to access it? Why is getBalance in the code allowed to access bankBalance?

Only functions declared within the constructor (where `bankBalance` is declared) can access it.  This is just plain javascript scoping rules, but comes in handy if you want to implement a private instance variable like this.

Comment: In your answer to my first question, you wrote "...if no property match is found [on the object], it will look on the prototype." Maybe I'm remembering incorrectly, but I remember an instance where a class, say "Animal", had a function, say "Animal.eat()=function()..." and a subclass of animal, say Dog, which didn't have its own eat function, couldn't use the eat() function unless it was changed to Animal.prototype.eat(). So why didn't JS lookup to the Animal superclass to find the eat function?

Comment: My second question's wording was a bit unclear. I meant, what is the difference between implementing a hypothetical function as this.functionName=function(){...} vs ClassName.functionName=function(){...}?

Comment: @user2752992 - If inheritance is set up properly, there is no case where methods of the superclass cannot be access by anyone.  All the methods are on the same object.

Comment: @user2752992 - are you asking about the difference between `this.functionName = function() {}` and `Classname.prototype.functionName = function() {}`?  If so, I added that to my answer to your point 2) above.   `Classname.functionName` is a static function that can only be accessed as `Classname.functionName` and cannot be accessed on any object created from `Classname`.  It's just a function that is a property of the constructor.  It isn't part of any object created by that constructor.  You have to use the prototype or assignment to `this.functionName` for that.

Answer (score 1):

1. `this.getBalance` exists in *every* instance, while `Person.prototype.getBalance` only on the `Person` class (function). In JavaScript, the inheritance is different from the traditional OOP language.
2. In your example, you cannot invoke `Person.getBalance`, no such function is declared.
3. Different.
4. In JavaScript, there is no `private` fields. You only can use *closure* to simulate this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over your questions in order.

1. `getBalance()` is defined on the `Person` object as an instance method. That simply means that every `Person` has its own `getBalance()` method.
2. This ties in with the above. If you had declared the method on `Person.prototype`, it would be shared across all `Person` objects you create, whereas now each `Person` has its own `getBalance()` method. The prototype approach can often provide a performance benefit for this reason.
3. Not sure what you mean here. Feel free to provide clarification and I'll try to answer.
4. A function declared inside another function has access to variables declared in the outer function, so `getBalance()` therefore has access to `bankBalance`. But since `bankBalance` isn't a property of the Person object, you don't have access to it via `john.bankBalance`, which is why that is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no difference
2. Yes, it will be global or local
3. There is no allowance
4. It's all the same